# Extending delete method of GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have a page with `GridView` pulling some data from a SQL Server database via Linq-to-SQL.

I made use of the automatically-generated buttons for deleting. However, in order for the delete command to work properly, I need to somehow make sure that one table in relation with those records I want to delete, is also modified (the related record in it is also looked up and deleted).

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Thanks,
Ondrej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a foreign-key [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with cascade delete.

### Delete Rule

Specify what happens if a user tries to delete a row with data that is involved in a foreign key relationship:

- **No Action** An error message tells the user that the deletion is not allowed and the DELETE is rolled back.
- **Cascade** Deletes all rows containing data involved in the foreign key relationship.
- **Set Null** Sets the value to null if all foreign key columns for the table can accept null values.

Comment: @Ondrej: Not only a lot of work but also - more important - a clean database. On this way it's impossible to get incosistencies even if you would delete a parent manually in SSMS.